# onSizeChange method - getWidth and GetHeight

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display pop windows with variable sizes. The layout consist of EditView and I set the text  on run time before displaying popup window. I want height of the  new layout. I am using following code . Can anyone help where I am wrong and on wrong approach to solve my problem.

- onsizechange method always return yOld and yNew Zero.

  private void info(String name, String Description, View v) {

  ```
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lo_popup_concerninfo,
              null, false);


      final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.lo_popup_concern_linearlayout);
      TextView tv_concernName = (TextView) popupView
              .findViewById(R.id.tv_concernName);
      final TextView tv_concernDesc = (TextView) popupView
              .findViewById(R.id.tv_concernDesc);
      Button btn_concernDone = (Button) popupView
              .findViewById(R.id.btn_concernDone);        

      tv_concernName.setText(name);
      tv_concernDesc.setText(Description);

      ll.addView(new MyCustomView(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

      Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
          //popupView.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
     popupView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,   View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED); 

        System.out.println("view.getMeasuredWidth() " +
                popupView.getMeasuredWidth());
                System.out.println("view.getMeasuredHeight() " +
                popupView.getMeasuredHeight());



      final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView,
              display.getWidth() - 40, popupView.getMeasuredHeight() + finalHeight);

      System.out.println("view" +
                popup.getHeight());

      popup.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
      popup.setFocusable(true);
      popup.update();

       class MyCustomView extends View{

       int viewWidth = 0;
       int viewHeight = 0;

       public MyCustomView(Context context) {
               super(context);
               System.out.println("ali1");
       }

       @Override
       protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
               super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);
               viewWidth = xNew;
               viewHeight = yNew;

               System.out.println("xNew " + xNew);
               System.out.println("yNew " + yNew);
               System.out.println("xOld " + xOld);
               System.out.println("yOld " + yOld);

       }


       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
               super.onDraw(canvas);

               String msg = "width: " + viewWidth + "height: " + viewHeight;
               System.out.println(msg);
       }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need for MyCustomClass and override onsizechanged method to get new size of layout in my case . I spent lot of hours because of small mistake. I was using following line of code that was restricting the TextView to stretch and wrap content.

```
 final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            display.getWidth() - 40, popupView.getMeasuredHeight() + finalHeight)
```

Now I am using following line

```
final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                display.getWidth() - 40, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and full method is as follow.

```
private void info(String name, String Description, View v) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lo_popup_concerninfo,
                null, false);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) popupView
                .findViewById(R.id.lo_popup_concern_linearlayout);

        TextView tv_concernName = (TextView) popupView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_concernName);
        final TextView tv_concernDesc = (TextView) popupView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_concernDesc);
        Button btn_concernDone = (Button) popupView
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_concernDone);
        tv_concernName.setText(name);
        tv_concernDesc.setText(Description);
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        popupView.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());

        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                display.getWidth() - 40, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popup.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.update();

        btn_concernDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                popup.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```